# 64 bit version of this code

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly

I managed to write a code that accepts a 32-bit integer and converts it to a digit-array to represent it in another number system
Question: How can i expand this to 64-bit?
In the Digital Mars C/C++ compiler:

```
void get_digits_asm()
{
    __asm
    {

        pushf       
        movd xmm0,eax
        movd xmm1,ebx
        movd xmm2,ecx
        movd xmm3,edx
        movd xmm4,edi

        mov eax,[variable_x]
        mov ebx,[number_system]
        mov ecx,0h
        mov edi,0h

        begin_loop:
        mov edx,0h
        div ebx             
        lea edi,digits  
        mov [edi+ecx*4],edx
        add ecx,01h
        cmp eax,ebx
        ja begin_loop

        mov edx,0
        div ebx
        lea edi,digits
        mov [edi+ecx*4],edx
        inc ecx
        mov [digits_total],ecx


        movd edi,xmm4//pop edi
        movd edx,xmm3//pop edx
        movd ecx,xmm2//pop ecx
        movd ebx,xmm1//pop ebx
        movd eax,xmm0//pop eax
        popf            
    }

}
```

When this function returns, it gives the LSB to MSB arranged array of digits.

Example: 5 is 101 in the number-system 2. 232343435 is 54545... in system 8. I want to learn how can i make this in 64 bit. My OS is 32 bit. My CPU is pentium-M centrino-laptop How can i do this?

Comment: Do you want to process 64 bits of data, or make the code run on a 64-bit OS? Two different questions...

Comment: i need to process 64 bit data 128 bit even 1024 bit data. Can i enable long mode in my winows XP(32 bit)?

Comment: No, you cannot use 64-bit registers without the support of the OS. You could, however, probably run your loop several times and process 32 bits each time.

Comment: i need to use xmm8-xmm15 . i am  using xmm0-xmm7 now. they are not enough. who is using my registers? windows?

Comment: Nobody is using those registers. The extra registers need an instruction prefix that is only available in 64-bit mode. You will have to save and restore instead, or reorganize the code so it uses fewer registers (hard). There *are* advantages of running  in 64-bit mode. Twice as many registers is one.

Comment: is changing windows xp32 to xp64 hard? Do i need full install?

Comment: This is a new question. :-) But yes, there is no upgrade from 32 to 64 bit Windows, it will be a complete reinstall. And Windows XP-64 is extremely rare, it would have to be Windows 7 or soon Windows 8.

Comment: i write movd xmm14,eax in the flat assembler. and it gives warnings and doesnt compile. How can i forcedly compile that code?

Comment: does 64-bit mean, instructions can be 8-bytes long?

Comment: The Pentium M doesn't support 64-bit. End of story... You'll need a new computer.

Comment: No, 64-bit mode is the "long mode" you talked about earlier. It doesn't directly affect the size of instructions, which can be 1-n bytes already. You cannot access extra registers or wider registers in 32-bit mode, because there are no instruction encodings for that. If you have more questions, please ask these as new questions.

Comment: ok. when i buy a new cpu, i will buy it 64 bit and will buy 64 bit os. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use

```
 mov edx,0h
```

before

```
 div ebx
```

in your `begin_loop:`.

If you want to process 64-bit numbers, then use the EDX register to store the upper 32 bits of you number. So, if you number is

```
int64_t variable_x;
```

then load it into EDX/EAX pair.

Instead of

```
mov eax,[variable_x]
```

do

```
mov esi, variable_x
mov eax, [esi]
mov edx, [esi + 4]
```

I hope you get it. Sorry if I forgot the exact addressing rules of x86.

Of course, since you destroy the EDX on each iteration, you might use the stack or one more register to store it.

Your problem has nothing to do with the 64-bit long mode, DIV instruction supports 64-bit integers. They are just stored as pairs.